# How to use a proxy in dropnet

Tags: c#, proxy, dropnet

I tried to create a tool with dropnet.
Now there's a big Problem: we have a Proxy in the Office

How can i use this Proxy automaticaly for every Connection?

Thx
damon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you using DropNet on? At the moment a proxy is not supported on Windows Phone or Windows Store Apps.

But in full .NET the DropNetClient instance has a property called Proxy which is a IWebProxy interface. https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Client/Client.cs#L65

I'm not 100% sure how it works as I didn't implement that feature but looking at the code it might need some work to get it to work as the property seems to only be used by the Constructor and you can't set it before calling the constructor which is strange.

If you get it working let me know and I'll update the documentation.